# Reversed sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function

How do I return an array of integers from n to 1 where n>0? I wrote this code:

```
def reverse_seq(num)
reverse_seq = []
[].reverse { |num| num > 0; num += 1 }
return []
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could create an enumerator via [`downto`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Integer.html#downto-method) that goes from `n` down to `1` and turn that into an array:

```
n = 5

n.downto(1).to_a
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

or you could call [`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#new-method) with a block and calculate each value based on its index:

```
n = 5

Array.new(n) { |i| n - i }
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

or you could traverse a `n..1` range by passing `-1` to [`step`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html#method-i-step):

```
n = 5

(n..1).step(-1).to_a
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
(1..5).to_a.reverse
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Or if you want to iterate over those elements in a next step anyway, use `reverse_each`

```
(1..5).reverse_each { |i| puts i }
#=> 5
    4
    3
    2
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.7 you can also use [`Enumerator#produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce) which is my new favorite way to create sequences.

For your use case:

```
def reverse_seq(num)
  Enumerator.produce(num) {|prev| prev.positive? ? prev.pred : raise(StopIteration) }
end
```